# Identify the entries within .ssh/known_hosts?

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to identify each entry within `.ssh/known_hosts`? Having created connections with many machines, I now find myself having many entries within that file. Some of the entries come from connecting to virtual machines that do not exist anymore. All those entries look a bit like:

```
|1|ULDIElsaflkauvi83nlakfd83ölkjdsflLJDLJF389==
|1|UDkkenm88fKNDK8NDKLJh8393lLDf8adfadrlj32rl==
|1|MEUdiyf882nflLld89200KDLj8D8323kljhnLIDKJL==
```

Is there a way of knowing which entry is for which client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got HashKnownHosts set to "yes" in your ssh_config file, so the hostnames aren't available in plaintext.

If you know the hostname you're looking for ahead of time, you can search for it with:

```
ssh-keygen -H -F hostname
```

Here's the relevant section from the ssh-keygen(1) man page:

> -F hostname
>            Search for the specified hostname in a known_hosts file, listing
>            any occurrences found.  This option is useful to find hashed host
>            names or addresses and may also be used in conjunction with the
>            -H option to print found keys in a hashed format.

For example

```
ssh-keygen -H -F github.com
```

Will output the corresponding known_hosts entry. If there is no output, it means this host has no entry in your file.

Comment: It's worth noting that HashKnownHosts is a security feature, introduced to make it hard for an attacker who gains access to your system to use the known_hosts file to identify other hosts you access, and thereby gain a target list for rolling their compromise further.  It's not there *just* to frustrate you...